# Prove: $x^3+y^3\geq \frac{1}{4}(x+y)^3$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

> Prove: $x^3+y^3\geq \frac{1}{4}(x+y)^3$ for all $x,y$ positive.

Let's look at 
$$\begin{split} &(x-y)^2(x+y)\geq 0 \\
\iff &(x-y)(x+y)(x-y)\geq 0\\
\iff& (x-y)(x^2-y^2)\geq 0 \\
\iff &x^3-xy^2-yx^2+y^3\geq 0\\
\iff & 3x^3+3y^3\geq +3xy^2+3yx^2\\
\iff &3x^3+3y^3\geq (x+y)^3 -x^3-y^3 \\
\iff & 4x^3+4y^3\geq (x+y)^3 \\
\iff & x^3+y^3\geq \frac{1}{4}(x+y)^3
\end{split}$$

is the proof valid? is there a shorter way?

Comment: what are $x$ and $y$, I mean their domain?

Comment: If you're okay with appealing to convexity, you can note that it's equivalent to $\frac{x^3+y^3}{2}\ge \left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^3$, which comes from the convexity of $x\to x^3$ for $x>0$.

Comment: @KushalBhuyan added

Comment: @πr8 can you please elaborate why is $\frac{x^3+y^3}{2}\geq (\frac{x+y}{2})^2$ true?

Comment: A convex function is [midpoint convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties) (If you know $f(x)  = x^3$ is convex) @gbox

Comment: My first thought would be to set $f(x) = lhs-rhs$ and using calculus to prove that it can't pass 0 without it being a local minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this proof valid?

Your proof is valid and correct. However, it would be better if you prove that an equivalent statement is true, from an inequality, instead of doing the opposite.

$$\begin{split} & x^3+y^3\geq \frac{1}{4}(x+y)^3 \\
\iff & 4x^3+4y^3\geq (x+y)^3 \\
\iff &3x^3+3y^3\geq (x+y)^3 -x^3-y^3 \\
\iff & 3x^3+3y^3\geq 3xy^2+3yx^2\\
\iff &x^3-xy^2-yx^2+y^3\geq 0\\
\iff& (x-y)(x^2-y^2)\geq 0 \\
\iff &(x-y)(x+y)(x-y)\geq 0\\
\iff &(x-y)^2(x+y)\geq 0 \\
\end{split}$$

Which is clearly true when $x+y \geq 0$

> Is there a shorter method ?

The given inequality is equivalent to

$$4(x^3+y^3)(x+y)=(1+1)(1+1)(x^3+y^3)(x+y) \geq (x+y)^4$$ which is true by Hölder's inequality

Comment: What do you mean by "it would be better if you prove a true statement from an inequality, instead of doing the opposite."?

Comment: @gbox Please check the edits.

Answer (score 4):

In general
$$x^p + y^p \geq \dfrac{(x+y)^p}{2^{p-1}}$$
which follows from Holder's inequality, which states that
$$\Vert a \Vert_p \Vert b \Vert_q \geq \vert a\cdot b \vert$$
where $\dfrac1p + \dfrac1q = 1$. To obtain your result, take $a = (x,y)$ and $b=(1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Using AM-GM Inequality:
$$\frac{x+y}2\ge\sqrt{xy}\iff xy\le \left(\frac{x+y}2\right)^2$$

We have:
\begin{align}
(x+y)^3&=x^3+y^3+3xy(x+y)\\
&\le x^3+y^3+3\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)^2(x+y)\\
&=x^3+y^3+\frac 34 (x+y)^3
\end{align}

So 
$$x^3+y^3\ge \frac14 (x+y)^3$$

Comment: I can't see how AM-GM Inequality was used

Comment: See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Write $x=m+z$ and $y=m-z$, so that $x+y=2m\gt0$.  Then

$$x^3+y^3=(m+z)^3+(m-z)^3=2m^3+6mz^2\ge2m^3={1\over4}(2m)^3={1\over4}(x+y)^3$$

Note that we only need for the *midpoint* $m$ between $x$ and $y$ to be positive in order for the inequality to hold.